# free jqGrid: how to change icons and syles layout

Tags: jquery, free-jqgrid

I am using the Bootstrap CSS for style. How do i change the icons used on the grid. Also, I need to make it the table changes as it does not render well.

Please advise which classes and icons or those can be assigned by API?
Also, how to support "scope" of the CSS? so that it will not conflict with original application?

**UPDATE 1**
I have made the sizing and font changes sugguested by Oleg and it worked great!
Now, I need to know how to change these Icons or Increase the size of them?

see the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use [Font Awesome 4.7](http://fontawesome.io/) for icons. You need just include CSS of Font Awesome (from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`, for example) add `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option of jqGrid.

One more advice: the next version of Bootstrap don't have old buildin Glyphicons  icon font (see [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components)). Bootstrap 4 recommend Font Awesome as one of possible alternatives.

If you need more deep replacing of icons you have to specify which one you need to replace to which one.

**UPDATE**: I created for you an example of customizing some background colors of free jqGrid, which use Bootstrap, and customizing the font size: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/90qmjean/. The demo uses the following CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-titlebar .ui-jqgrid-title,
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-errorbar .ui-jqgrid-error,
.ui-jqdialog.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqdialog-titlebar .ui-jqdialog-title {
      font-size: 18px;
}
.ui-jqdialog.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .FormData .CaptionTD {
      font-size: 16px;
}
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap > .ui-jqgrid-view,
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-pager-control .ui-pg-input,
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap > .ui-jqgrid-pager,
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-pager-control .ui-pg-selbox,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view input,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view select,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view textarea,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view button {
      font-size: 14px;
}
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap > .ui-jqgrid-view .fa,
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap > .ui-jqgrid-pager .fa,
.jqgrow .ui-pg-div > span.fa {
      font-size: 18px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    padding: 0 .3em 0 .3em;
}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgfirstrow > td {
    padding: 0 .3em 0 .3em;
}
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap,
.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap.ui-jqdialog modal-content {
      border: 1px solid #003380;
}
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-caption,
.ui-jqdialog.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqdialog-titlebar {
    background-color: #0073e6;
    color: white;
}
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {
    background-color: #99ccff;
}
.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager,
.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager {
    background-color: #cce6ff;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.active,
.table > tbody > tr > td.active, 
.table > thead > tr > th.active,
.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.active,
.ui-jqgrid-actions .ui-pg-div.active {
    background-color: #e6f2ff;
}
.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.active,
.ui-jqgrid-actions .ui-pg-div.active {
    border-radius: .4em;
}
.ui-jqgrid-btable tr.jqgrow.success,
.ui-jqgrid-btable tr.jqgrow.success > td {
    background-color: #ccffee;
}
.ui-jqgrid-btable tr.jqgrow.active,
.ui-jqgrid-btable tr.jqgrow.active > td
.ui-jqgrid-btable > tbody > tr.jqgrow.active > td:hover,
.ui-jqgrid-btable.table-hover > tbody > tr.jqgrow.active:hover > td,
.ui-jqgrid-btable.table-hover > tbody > tr.jqgrow:hover > .active,
.ui-jqgrid-btable.table-hover > tbody > tr.jqgrow.active:hover > th {
    background-color: #ffffe6;
}
.ui-jqgrid-btable tr.jqgrow.active.success,
.ui-jqgrid-btable tr.jqgrow.active.success > td {
    background-color: #e6e6ff;
}
.ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close.active {
    background-color: #ccffee;
}
```

I think that you can easy modify the above CSS rules to produce the font size and the colors/background-colors which you need.

Comment: Oleg, I am using Boostrap4 with Font Awesome. Can you direct me how to change the look and feel of the entire grid table? which CSS classes i should be looking into? I need to change Table Header, Rows and footer with more spacing, increase font, row height etc

Comment: @dev.sforce: [The old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping-bootstrap-glyph.htm) shows how to changed bachground colors. Look at [the comment](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/188#issuecomment-165462243) for CSS rules, which changes the padding. After that one can just change `font-size`.

Comment: Oleg, i have added UPDATE 1, can you please provide me feedback?

Comment: @dev.sforce: You should use the CSS rule like `.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap > .ui-jqgrid-view .fa, .ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap > .ui-jqgrid-pager .fa, .jqgrow .ui-pg-div > span.fa { font-size: 18px; }`. I created for you the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/90qmjean/ and wrote **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have applied the same style i am using to your demo:https://jsfiddle.net/SalesforceDev/90qmjean/2/ Can you direct me how to change the Icons and size?

Comment: @dev.sforce: Just read my previous comment. https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/90qmjean/3/

Comment: Again, Hats off for your community service!!. I am java guy more server side, but this grid made me now front-end guy ;)

Comment: @dev.sforce: You are welcome! Some years ago I had no idea about web development and used more C/C++ and later C#. Then I had to study seriously SQL, then HTML/CSS/JavaScript and many other web technologies. Things are changed quickly. I'm wonder what will be your main subject of interest in the software development 5-10 years later. :-)